# Why does font of the background text change on applying CSS3 animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why does the font style of the background text change on applying css3 animation opacity and transform scale? I've some text contents in my page. I also have a click me link. When someone clicks "Click me!" I show a popup with css3 animation. But I observe the font change on animation.

Here is my code with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanmandal2/MYGU5/).

```
.fade-in-scale{
animation-name: fade-in-scale;
-webkit-animation-name: fade-in-scale;  
-moz-animation-name: fade-in-scale;

animation-duration: .5s;    
-webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
-moz-animation-duration: .5s;   

animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;    

animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in-scale {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(.7);      
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
}           
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-scale {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(.7);      
}
100% {

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
}       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with font rendering. Here is a solution. Add `body { -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; }` to the css file.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MYGU5/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation, so I can't comment, instead I have to do everything in the form of an answer. Are you referring to the chunk of Lorem Ipsum that shows in the background of the pop-up window when you open it? And if so the reason that you can see it is because the fade-in effects modifies opacity to bring it in, therefore the background shows through in the beginning. And if that isn't what you are referring to could you elaborate a bit? Because I didn't see anything else noticable.

Comment: Yes it the font of the Lorem Ipsum that is changed. As you said, the fade-in effects modifies opacity but I think it should change the opacity of the fade-in-scale div and not other element in the page.

Comment: When I use the fiddle there is no font change on the Lorem Ipsum.